# Extend rails simpleform functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails app with the "simpleform" and "bootstrap-datepicker-rails" gems.

I try to make the view code more readable like this:

```
f.input :birthday, :mydatefield, :options => {:icon => "calendar", :data-date => "21.12.2012", :data-format => "dd-mm-yyyy"}
```

At this moment I write this:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="user_birthday" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <%= f.input_field :birthday, :disabled => true %>
    <span class="add-on">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

or this

```
<%= f.input :birthday, :wrapper => :datepicker, :wrapper_html=> {id: "user-birthday", class: "date"} do %>
    <%= f.input_field :birthday, :disabled => true %>
    <%= content_tag :span, :class => "add-on" do %>
        <%= content_tag :i, :style => "color:grey", :class => "icon-calendar" do
        end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

to get my result:

[image: Simpleform with bootstrap icon and datepicker]

Both of above are making this result, which works well:

```
<div class="control-group string required date" id="user-birthday">
    <label class="string required control-label" for="user_birthday"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Birthday</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append">
            <input class="string required disabled" disabled="disabled" id="user_birthday" name="user[birthday]" size="50" type="text" />
            <span class="add-on">
                <i class="icon-calendar" style="color:grey"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to parse variables to the wrapper

```
:wrapper_html=> => {:data-date => "21-12-2012"}
```

it throw errors...

What I have to do? I am quite new on extending gems.

What I have to write to get this working?

- SimpleForm Wrapper?
- app/inputs/datepickerInput.rb?
- initializer/datepicker.rb?
- Helper Method?

An example will be VERY helpful!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: :wrapper_html=> => {:data-date => "21-12-2012"}
are you sure in this line of description? since it has syntax error. It should look like :wrapper_html => {:data-date => "21-12-2012"}

Comment: sorry, typo. Is only here on stackoverflow. In my code it's correct.

The main problem is the "-" in the attributes.

So a "data-date-format" or "data-blah-blah" raises an exception when I try :data-blah => "xxx" it fails
When I try :test => "xxx" it seems to be working

Comment: these attributes can be passed in quotes, 'data-blah' => 'value'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched back to the rails implemented forms. For me (as a beginner) simple_form seems not to be clear enough.

For my solution above I created a FormBuilder:

```
class BootstrapFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

  def birthday_field_with_hint_and_icons (name, *args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    birthday_field_icons(name) + hint(options[:hint])
  end

  def birthday_field_icons(name, *args)
    dd = 'data-date'
    ddf = 'data-date-format'
    content_tag :div, class: "input-append date", dd => 18.years.ago.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), ddf => "dd-mm-yyyy", id: "user_birthday" do
      text_field(name, :disabled => 'disabled') + icon("icon-calendar")
    end
  end

  private

  def icon(icon)
    content_tag :span, class: "add-on" do
      content_tag :i, style: "color: grey;", class: icon do
      end
    end
  end

  def hint(hint)
    content_tag :span, class: "help-block" do
      hint
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom field. Follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-input-components) to do that.

Comment: For my understanding this tut is a little bit spare. It works, but not completly . I have made a string variable like '"options = "data-date-format"' and I used it later in the code instead of direct writing. But my approach was also to use a wrapper. (A combination of wrapper and variables).

Maybe a partial will also do that stuff?

Comment: yep, a partial could work. But I'm not sure if it is syntactically right.

Comment: ok. thanks for your suggestions. I will try a partial and post the result here. :-)